# Reduce font size in TTF file

Tags: resize, font-design, font-size, ttf

I have a font that I downloaded that I would like to apply to an existing document, but the font size I need is consistently 5.5pt less than the font size in the TTF file I downloaded. So if I want to use the font, I have to go through the document and change each instance of that font to have a size 5.5pt less that it was before.

Is there any way to scale the font down so I don't need to change the font size over and over in my document?

I apologize if this question is novice or impossible, I am quite new to graphic design.

---

### **Text with font size of 24pt**

[image]

### **Text with font size of 19.5pt (5.5pt less)**

[image]
***This is the font size I would like to get by default, so I dont need to change all instances of this font in my document with font size 5.5pt less***

Please let me know if this is possible, and if so, how to so it.

Thanks!!

Comment: What is the programme used to write/edit the document?

Comment: What if you use 6pt. Should it then be 0.5pt? I assume what you really want is it to be proportionally smaller not always 5.5pt smaller.

Comment: I am using FontForge @gms0ulman No, I thought the same so I started playing with the ratios but they would work with some and not for others. Decreasing by 5.5 always worked though

Comment: @Cai see above comment

Answer (score 1):

I think for this time, you have to change all the font size in your document manually.

In Microsoft Word and most Adobe programs have character and paragraph styles. In general, you should create styles, set all your formatting rules in a style, and then apply the style throughout your document.

In the future, you just need to modify the styles rather than the who document.

[See here for more detail about styles in InDesign.](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/paragraph-character-styles.html)

Comment: The concept of styles existing is nearly any application worth using for significant amounts of text. Paragraph and character styles available in Microsoft Word, LibreOffice Writer, Adobe InDesign, Scribus. I'm always amazed how few non-technical people are not familiar with style in Word and send me things that have been manually formatted.